# Fix misspelled column name in every table of a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, alter, database-management

I've got a `SQL Server` database running in `SSMS` which contains ~75 tables. I've just realized every table has a `modfiedBy` column header, which is misspelled and should instead be spelled `modifiedBy`.

Is there a way to change (`ALTER`??) all these column headers programatially via `SQL`, so that I don't have to right click --> design and manually respell it on every single table? Could anyone provide an example that may work?

Comment: @Lamu I can't be 100% sure if it's the same on every table, but I believe most if not all of them will be `varchar(50)`. (there may be one or two in there w/ `nvarchar(50)` but I can change these myself.

Comment: Don't worry i was havinga mental blipp anyway. You'll need dynamic sql. Example on the way.

Comment: Are any of those columns referenced in keys, stored procedures, views or whatever? What version of SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a dynamic SQL solution for this. This should do the job; provided it doesn't break any Constraints, keys. It also won't update any objects referencing the old name.

```
USE YourDatabase;
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(10) +
                         N'EXEC sp_rename ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name] + N'.' + t.[name] + N'.' + c.[name],N'''') + N',''modifiedBy'',''COLUMN'';'
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                       JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                  WHERE c.[name] = N'modfiedBy'
                  FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,1,N'');
PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```